# Can possiblity of hash collision be "zero" when we hash same file in different formats?

Tags: hash, binary

Let's say I have a file A, which is any normal file (pdf, jpeg, mp3 etc.)

 Now I get the binary dump of file, say another file B{A}.

 And the hexdump of file say, file H{A}.

 Now I hash all the three files with any 256 bit HASH (SHA256, BLAKE256 etc.)

 I want to know that :

 1. What is the possiblity of hash collision in this case (Considering if somehow I find a collison in case of file A, I still can generate the hex and binary dump of that file to see if hashes of B{A} and H{A} matches or not).

2. Will it still be 1/256* 256* 256? Or

3. Will there be 0 collision ? (Considering collision between exactly same size of files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximating a Hash function $h$ as a function that maps each word in $\{0,1\}^*$ to a word in $\{0,1\}^{256}$ chosen uniformly at random, you can find the probability that at least one of the events:

- $h(A)=h(B\{A\})$,
- $h(A)=h(H\{A\})$,
- $h(B\{A\})=h(H\{A\})$

is true by looking at the complementary probability. The probability that $h(A)$, $h(B\{A\})$, and $h(H\{A\})$ are all distinct is $1 \cdot (1 - \frac{1}{2^{256}}) \cdot (1 - \frac{2}{2^{256}})$. Then, the probability of having at least one collision is then:
$$
1- \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{256}}\right) \cdot \left(1 - \frac{2}{2^{256}}\right) \approx 2.6 \cdot 10^{-77}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for explanation.